# Как делать POST запрос с помощью питона с авторизацией

Tags: python, html, post, веб-сайт

Есть сайт который делает post запрос, как с помощью питона делать POST запрос с авторизацией Bearer .Ссылку на сайт дать не смысла потому что там авторизоваться можно только в определенной сети.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал так:

```
import requests

data={"orderId":"b449e695-123-23-9f29-43999665ad6f","comment":" "}
url = 'https://job.сайт.ru/api/order/response/make'

import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer удалено'
}



response = requests.post(
    url,
    data=data,
    headers=headers,
    timeout=30
)

print(response.status_code)  

result = response.json()
print(result)
```

но выходит ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    result = response.json()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Если из строки сайта убрать "job." то ошибки нет, но само собой это не работает:)

Comment: Этот сайт делает запрос к другому сайте или браузер делает запрос к этому сайту?

Comment: Вы можете просто в браузере открыть средства разработчика (f12) и там найти этот запрос. Посмотреть данные, отправленные, заголовки и так далее

Comment: @FroggerProgger Да знаю про это только там не понятно что именно передает браузер в POST запрос и как они расположены.

Comment: @user580418 Там всё есть и параметры запроса все есть - и URL и тело POST-запроса и куки.

Comment: @CrazyElf там на сайте есть свой интерфейс, если посмотреть через меню разработчика в браузере то там видно что происходит POST команда на определенный сайт,но не понятно что какие именно передаются аргументы

Comment: Ну добавьте в вопрос скриншот как вы там видите этот запрос.

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил, на последний фотографии была убрана информация, отображается оно верно

Comment: Ну вот у вас там "полезная нагрузка" - это, видимо, и есть `JSON`, который через этот `POST` отсылается.

Comment: Я пытался отправить его через питон с библеотекой Request и указанием ссылки, но получил ошибку response 401, пытался также отправить с этим и куки но получил туже самую ошибку

Comment: Код вашей попытки приложите к вопросу. И какая ошибка получилась тоже

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил

Comment: Так 401 это проблема с авторизацией. Нужно так и вопрос озаглавить и искать ответы насчёт авторизации, отправка самого запроса тут не проблема.

Comment: Первое: можно много говорить, где лучше и как лучше смотреть, но ничего лучшего (по моему опыту) нет, как закинуть ваш curl в какой-нибудь конвертер: правой кнопкой мыши по POST-запросу -> Копировать -> Копировать как cURL (bash). Ссылку не даю, чтобы не посчитали рекламой. Иногда data нужно передавать в requests в параметр data, иногда в json и ничего лучше эмпирического подхода походу нет
Второе: часто, если есть подобная ошибка `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`, результат лучше смотреть в response.text, ведь json, это по сути сериализация того же text, который вам пришел

Comment: Десериализация*. Но так как тут явно написано char 0, то там скорее всего пустая строка. Советую пересмотреть data, которую вы отправляете. Не исключено, что отправить нужно именно через параметр json в requests, а не data. Может не хватает какого-то куки с авторизацией, или неправильно указали токен в headers - все зависит от сайта. Но это так, предположения

Comment: @DeNRuDi спасибо за ответ, я уже нашел способ как это исправить библиотека requests отлично работает и с такой ссылкой про авторизацию да скорее всего там чего то не хватает но это понятно потому что там очень много что передается если судить по меню разработчика в браузере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь @DeNRuDi и @CrazyElf. Рабочий более метод такой

```
import requests


data={"orderId":"sdfhghs-f208-4f55-9f29-43999665ad6f","comment":" "}
url = 'https://job.sdfhd.ru/api/order/response/make'


headers = {
   'Authorization': 'Bearer ey12'
}


r = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=data)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: Точно get? У get же нет тела запроса, data куда пойдёт?